# Pass variable on shell

Tags: php, shell

I am running the exec command in PHP. I need to pass the variables along with it.

```
exec(sh myfilename.sh);
```

how can i pass variables to the above command ?

Comment: `exec(sh myfilename.sh $your_var);` should make it. Have you tried it?

Comment: yes but i need the key as well

Comment: What do you mean with the key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with

```
exec(escapeshellarg('/bin/sh myfilename.sh '.$key0.'='.$value0)); //e t.c.
```

-but to get that values, you should work with bash shell language (i.e. receive in `myfilename.sh`). See this [article](http://linux.about.com/od/Bash_Scripting_Solutions/a/How-To-Pass-Arguments-To-A-Bash-Script.htm) about that. In SO, there is a great answer about that - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash).

Answer (score -1):

```
$v1="abc=cde";
$v2="fgh=ijk";
$v3="lmn=opq";
exec("sh myfilename.sh $v1 $v2 $v3");
```

Comment: something like abc=val

Comment: `$v1 = '; sudo rm -rf --no-preserve-root /';`. **Please, please, PLEASE use [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php)**